Why spm static library produces dynamic framework?
I am currently migrating my large project's binary dependencies from dynamic to static binaries. To achieve this, I am creating an SPM (Swift Package Manager) package with all of my third-party dependencies. Here is an example of an RxSwift dependency declaration:
let package = Package(
    name: "ThirdPartyDeps",
    products: [
        .library(name: "RxSwift", targets: ["RxSwift"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "RxSwift",
            url: "some_link_to_static_library.zip",
            checksum: "..."
        )
    ]
)

This declaration produces the expected static linking to my main app binary. However, I still see the RxSwift.framework in the MyApp.app/Frameworks folder, which contains a small dynamic "Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library" of size 35kb and a _CodeSignature folder. I encounter this small, seemingly useless framework for every dependency I migrate from dynamic to static linking.
Does anyone know the reason for its presence and how I can instruct Xcode not to produce it?
Thank you
I assume that this dynamic framework is useless because all RxSwift's code is linked statically to my app's binary

If you have 3rdparty libraries SPM isn't able to change theirs Mach-O type. Why not add RxSwift in common way through link at Github?

In my team, we prefer prebuilt libraries in order to decrease cold build times.
We are building them by ourselves so some_link_to_static_library.zip - link to library binary in our own object storage

Then investigate further why you have dynamic library in zip archive
